# How to cope with "saving" dialog remaining open?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to save a workbook;

```vb
wb.SaveAs sTmp, FileFormat:=51
```

where sTmp is the complete valid file path (including .xlsx at the end) and fileformat 51 is .xlsx.
The new workbook is stored in a network location. (This might be part of the problem but I can't find anything related.)

This code runs smoothly 9 out of 10 times. Sometimes the "saving" dialog box remains open, even though the file has been saved, causing the code to hang on the SaveAs line.
If I click the cancel button the code continues and I can open the file.

Is there any time-out function if a line of code takes too long to execute? (Googling for time out returns user inactivity questions or SQL related problems)

Update;

Generating the string is not the problem, sTmp is a validated string. If the string (or any other input for that matter) would be wrong or the specified path/file name would be wrong, doesn't exist, has to be replaced or contains illegal characters VBA will throw an error.

To clarify; when executing this line the workbook is actually saved. Excel pops up a dialog box "saving workbook to (path)" with a progress bar. This pop up won't go away and the code hangs on above line, as if it is waiting for a hand shake. When the progress bar is killed (i.e. pressing the cancel button) the code resumes as normal.

Comment: I dont get it: you seem to be getting the file name `sTmp` from a file dialog? If so, the dialog should close before even your line of code executes. What did I misunderstand?

Comment: You should share where the `sTmp` is being set in your code.

Comment: Did you find any solution.. I'm facing similar problem too

Comment: I too am facing this issue. This is the only thing holding this workbook back from being rolled out in our organisation as it won't be a great experience for users.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution, however I did manage to narrow the problem; It only occurs on network locations and probably Microsoft Sharepoint disrupts the process as well. A workaround for me was to save the files locally and then move the saved files to the desired location.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error show up after a small code modification. It was the use of the `Kill` function.

After substituting the following code, the issue no longer occurred.

```vb
With New FileSystemObject
    If .FileExists(yourFilePath) Then
        .DeleteFile yourFilepath
    End If
End With
```